# Did Ibn Hajar Really Rejected The Narrations of Al-Amash through Abu Muawiyyah bin Abdur Rahman?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar, ilm-ar-rijal

Al-Amash is a reliable narrator who is found in Bukhari [HERE](https://muflihun.com/bukhari/81/774). However, I have read in an online source that Ibn Hajar has rejected the narrations of Al-Amash in which he quoted Abu Muawiyyah bin Abdur Rahman. It is said that Ibn Hajar has stated that all the narrations in which Al-Amash quoted Abu Muawiyyah bin Abdur Rahman are **Munkir**!

I have read that these statements of Ibn Hajr are written in his book Tahdhib Al-Tahdhib by Imam Ibn al-Hajar al Asqalani, volume 3, Page 351.

I do not have access to this book. It will be very, very kind of someone if anyone can please check whether Ibn Hajar really rejected Al-Amash's narrations in which he quoted Abu Muawiyyah bin Abdur Rahman?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that you've misinterpreted whatever you've found ibn Hajar may have rejected the ahadith from Abu Mu'awiyyah from al-A'mash not the opposite (BTW the biography of al-A'mash appears in Volume 4 according my research). Al-A'mash is widely known as trustworthy and his companions called him the "qur'an" to show that what he reported was truthful. Even if he practiced tadless as he met Anas ibn Malik, but didn't narrate from him without any intermediate. Abu Muawiyyah basically doesn't appear in the first list of narrators of al-A'mash.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - But why did Ibn Hajr rejected Abu  Muawiyyah from Al-Amash? Are there more than one Abu Muawiyyah? I am not sure who this Abu Muawiyyah is, but according to [THIS SOURCE](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1462&bk_no=60&flag=1&fbclid=IwAR2G-NX-6_KmXim21j2tuGYHR7xSIRj71vCSeLMjoXR7kbVc0lArOktzTeY), Imam Ahmad & Yahya bin Ma'in praised him especially when narrating from Al-Amash. Someone told me he is Muhammad bin Khazim, Mawla Bani Saad bin Zaid, Minat Bin Tamim, Al-Hafizh Al-Hajjah Abu Muawiya Al-Saadi, the blind Kufi. ARE THERE TWO ABU MUAWIYYAH?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the biography of Abu Mu'awiyyah. At first site it doesn't look like there could be two Abu Mu'awiyyah which are related to al-A'mash. Further what I've read so far is that Abu Mu'awiyyah is considered as reliable when narrating from al-A'mash, but not from others. Which seems to be in accordance to the statement of imam a-Dhahabi. But do you have an example of such a narration?

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Ok, brother, Now let me unveil to you my real purpose for asking this question. I have asked this question because I am writing a refutation of the Qadiani cult. They try to attack the authenticity of a narration of Ibn Abbas that says that Jesus (AS) ascended into the heavens, since it would clearly disprove their cult. Qadianis claim that there are two issue with the narration: 1) It contains narrator Minhal Ibn Amr 2) Abu Muawiyyah narrated it from Al-Amash and Ibn Hajr criticized the narration that were narrated by Abu Muawiyyah from Al-Amash. (Comment Continued below)

Comment: @Medi1Saif - We already discussed the issue of Minhal Ibn Amr and I have concluded that he is reliable narrator. The second issue we need to address is WHY did Ibn Hajr claimed that the narrations that were narrated by Abu Muawiyyah from Al-Amash were not authentic. This is the main problem. If Abu Muawiyyah and Al-Amash both are reliable and if scholars like Yahya and Imam Ahmad have accepted their narrations, then I do not see any reason WHY Ibn Hajr rejected these narrations. The narration I am talking about is found in Sunan Kubra by Nasa'i. (Comment Continued Below)

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Here is the complete chain of narrators found in this narration:-

أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْعَلَاءِ، قَالَ: حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ، عَنِ الْأَعْمَشِ، عَنِ الْمِنْهَالِ بْنِ عَمْرٍو، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَيْرٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ:

As you can see that Abu Mua'wiyyah has narrated this narration from Al-Amash.

Qadianis argue that this narration is not authentic according to Ibn Hajr because Abu Muawiyyah narrated it from Al-Amash, but Imam Ahmad and Yahya have accepted such narration, I think. I am not sure if there are two Muawiyyahs here.

Comment: Well this chain looks weird because at least two of four narrators Abu Mu'awiyyah, al-A'mash, al-Minhal, Sa'id ibn Jubayr lived at the same time. And one must check whether they've met each other I mean al-Minhal and al-A'mash for example. While a meeting between al-Minhal and Sa'id ibn Jubayr and one between al-A'mash ans Abu Mu'awiyyah seems to be certain. But this is just a remark as if possible any author of a hadith compilation would avoid compiling a hadith with an extensively lengthy chain, as here as stated above we have 4 people who may have met each other the chain could be shorter.

Comment: Further if my last findings about al-Minhal are correct then he was at least a light shi'a(that wouldn be regarded as a weakness by default), but I have not enough proof for that. And as stated there are two different qualifications of Yahya ibn Ma'in about him and Ahmad was not too positive about him. So all together could result in a rather negative qualification. Further among the four narrators at least two or three lived in Kufa: al-Minhal, al-A'mash and maybe Abu Mu'awiyyah which makes a meeting possible.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Ibn Kathir has classified this narration as Sahih. It is highly unlikely that Ibn Kathir may have overlooked these possibilities. Please tell me if you have more info about the narrators in this narration and their possibilities of meeting each other.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - You wrote, "ibn Hajar may have rejected the ahadith from Abu Mu'awiyyah from al-A'mash not the opposite". Please can you tell me where did Ibn Hajr rejected ahadith from Abu Mu'awiyyah from al-A'mash? Is it in Tahdhib Al-Tahdhib?

Comment: This was just an assumption because I couldn't find anything confirming your information neither in Tahdhibvat-Tahdhib nor elsewhere. Secondly I'm not sure whether I've identified the correct Abu Mu'awiyyah yet in the named book.